# Running psycopg2 COPY_FROM for an empty table for multiple datasets in a loop will copy only the last entry

Tags: python, database, postgresql, transactions, psycopg2

I have multiple datasets with no conflicting primary keys or constraints, for which I need to run copy_from in a loop for every dataset to add them in the same table (the table is empty). Only the last dataset from the loop will be inserted.
This can be reproduced only if the table for witch is run is empty. If the table has even a single row, all the datasets will be inserted normally.
Note: For my use-case, I need to run multiple copy_from on the same table because I need to process the datasets independently on different subprocesses, running a single copy_from for all the merged datasets won't be a solution due to design considerations.
Postgres log is not showing anything. Also, the order of datasets in the loop does not matter. No matter the order, always only the last dataset in the loop will be inserted into the table.

```
for df, client_id in clients_data: #iteration trough a map of DataFrame objects and client ids
    with conn:
          with conn.cursor() as cursor:
              for chunk in df:
                  df = pipeline.clean_df(chunk, cursor, client_id) #doing some preprocessing irrelevant to the problem
                  copy_from_df(df, 'mytable', cursor, chunksize=50000)
      conn.close()
        
def copy_from_df(df: DataFrame,
                 table: str,
                 cursor,
                 chunk_size: int = __chunksize
                 ):
    try:
        for i in range(0, df.shape[0], chunk_size):
            buffer = StringIO()
            chunk = df.iloc[i:(i + chunk_size)]
            chunk.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False, sep='\t', na_rep='\\N', quoting=None)
            buffer.seek(0)
            cursor.execute(f'SET search_path TO {SCHEMA}')
            cursor.copy_from(buffer, table, columns=list(df.columns))
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        logger.error('COPY FROM Error: ' + str(e))
```

- OS: MacOS 11.6 Running psycopg2 from Docker 3.6.0
- Psycopg2: 2.9.2
- Python version: 3.9
- PostgreSQL version: 14.0-1.pgdg110+1

Comment: You have left out where `clients_data` is coming from? Also what `df = pipeline.clean_df(chunk, cursor)` is doing? Are you getting any errors? What does the Postgres log show during this? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question, thanks

Comment: No indication of what the Postgres log shows is actually hitting the database.

Comment: Well, yeah. It is hitting the database, because its actually inserting data, but only the last dataset of the loop. Like I said in the question, it doesnt matter in what order the datasets are when i iterate over the loop, always only the last one will be inserted

Comment: Yes, but are you seeing any indications there is any attempt to `COPY` the datasets before the last to the database? Also what is the log difference when '...table has even a single row, all the datasets will be inserted normally.'?